# Как экспортировать методы массива из файла?

Tags: javascript

есть метод массива:

```js
Array.prototype.sayHello = function(name) {
  console.log(`hello ${name}`);
}

module.exports.sayHello = sayHello;
```

Comment: А зачем его экспортировать? Вы уже изменили прототип.

Comment: А можно описать подробнее вашу задачу, просто код в вопросе лишен смысла.